# Upload File using httpwebrequest and rest api

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, file-upload, httpwebrequest

```
  I am trying to upload file using httpwebrequest and rest api
```

My code is like this i am not getting any error but i cannt able to upload file.
 `public static string RequestProfileUrl = "https://ws.onehub.com/workspaces/337426/folders/174352646/files/create?items[filename]=";`

```
  if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            byte[] bytearray = null;
            string name = "";
            long length = 0;
            string boundary = "----------------------------" +
            DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");
            name = file.FileName;
            Stream stream = file.InputStream;
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            bytearray = new byte[stream.Length];
            int count = 0;
            Stream memStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
            while (count < stream.Length)
            {
                bytearray[count++] = Convert.ToByte(stream.ReadByte());
            }
            //string baseAddress = "https://ws-api.onehub.com/workspaces/330201/files/";
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(RequestProfileUrl + name);
            request.Method = "PUT";
            request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data"; 
            request.ContentLength = bytearray.Length;
            request.GetRequestStream().Write(bytearray, 0, bytearray.Length);
            using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {

                int statusCode = (int)response.StatusCode;
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
                string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
```

i am not getting any error but my file is not uploading. i am not getting where is my error?
any question free to ask
Thanks in advance

Comment: What does webresponce result contain?

Comment: it contain the html design page of login page

Comment: Well then you would have to authenticate first and pass cookies with each request. A cookie enabled `WebClient` would work well.

Comment: wheather my code is ok for uploading file or not

Comment: How to pass cookies with each request?

Comment: Your code seems ok to me